# What is the procedure to carry out temple renovations or relocation?

Tags: temple, agamas, kashi

I read that a lot of temples have been demolished in Kashi in an effort to make the place visitor friendly. And that the same temples are now being relocated elsewhere in the kashi kshetra

I would like to know what scriptures say about this. Whats the procedure to follow to renovate/relocate temples. What are the repecursions if not followed? Do temples lose their sanctity ?

I am guessing information would be in Agamas, but any other valid sources will also help

Comment: It might be better to distinguish between the murthis and the physical building. The physical building is simply a building once the murthis are moved.